# Flutter - Fetch data of 'DateTimePickerFormField' value using controller

Tags: dart, flutter

I am a flutter beginner and trying to write an app.

For 'TextFormField' widget, we can get its value using the 'TextEditingController' like below,
`TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
 .
 .
 .
 expTitle = titleController.text;`

Is there a simillar way to get the value from 'DateTimePickerFormField' widget using controller ? Currently I pick the value via 'onChanged' property of DateTimePickerFormField like below

```
 onChanged: (dt) => setState(() => datePicked = dt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `TextEditingController` for `DateTimePickerFormField`